# docker-compose down failing: Too many open files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose in my production server. On my deploy process I run `docker-compose down`, deploy the application and run `docker-compose up`. However when I do `docker-compose down` it returns something like that:

```
ERROR: for ubuntu_php_run_1105  ('Connection aborted.', error(24, 'Too many open files'))

ERROR: for ubuntu_php_run_821  ('Connection aborted.', error(24, 'Too many open files'))

ERROR: for ubuntu_php_run_820  ('Connection aborted.', error(24, 'Too many open files'))
```

If I run this command manually more times eventually it succeeds but I need to fix it because this error makes my deploy process to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... I'm running some jobs in background to do it I used `docker-compose run [service] [command]`, everytime it runs a new docker container is created and not killed. When I tried to `docker-compose down` there were a lot of containers and docker halted.

To solve I added `--rm` flag in `docker-compose`, this way when the command finished the conainer is removed:

```
docker-compose run --rm [service] [command]
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems to exceed maximum `open file descriptor` of the `container`, tries to increase the maximum number of open file with `nofile` of [ulimits](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#ulimits).

For example,

```
ulimits:
  nofile:
    soft: 98304
    hard: 98304
```

For command line

```
--ulimit nofile=98304:98304
```

Comment: Is there a way to "close" these files? Even if I increase this number eventually I will have the same problem.

Comment: Why do you think that?. do your application keep open files infinitely?

Comment: I thought this error was some files docker-compose was opening. I'm not aware of any "open file loop" in my application but I'll check it out. About the answer I'm running some tests to check if it is solved.